# How to quantify information in a time series?

Tags: time-series, entropy

I have a time series of daily values for one year and I want to find out which slice of the time series contains maximum information considering a slice is of 150 values. I calculated Shannon's Entropy of every slice moving 5 steps every time. To my surprise the Shannon's Entropy was all the same for all the slices. The time series look as below
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The python code is as below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import scipy

def ts_features(array):
    return scipy.stats.entropy(pd.Series(array).value_counts())

def window_with_highest_entropy(
        array: np.ndarray,
        window_size: int = None,
        step_size=5,
        return_all=False,
):
    """Finds the slice/window in a 1d array which has highest entropy.
    """
    assert array.size == len(array)

    if window_size is None:
        window_size = int(array.size * 0.4)

    endings = np.arange(window_size, array.size, step_size)
    entropies = {}
    for en in endings:
        st = en - window_size
        entropies[f'{st}_{en}'] = ts_features(array[st:en])

    if return_all:
        return entropies
    # return key with the highest entropy
    return max(entropies, key=entropies.get)
```

What feature should I use to extract the information holding capacity of time series.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vtx1.png

Comment: 1) What does "information" mean to you? 2) Shannon entropy makes an assumption about independence, no? You lack that independence in a time series.

Comment: @Dave I don't have much understanding of Shannon's entropy. I have 40 years of data from hundreds of sites and I want to train a machine learning model. Training on all the data will be computationally very expensive. I want to train on reduced amount of data because the time series I am using is rainfall which shows values during summer months most of the year and remains null during winter months.